# Rails: How to get directly related records, but in context of a relationship :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got kind of a strange case, in which I have a DayReport that has many Reports, which belong to an Account. I set-up my DayReport module using a has_many through for the accounts:

```
class DayReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  has_many :accounts, -> { order(:last_name) }, through: :reports
end
```

What I would like to do now, is get all the accounts and display all the reports for that account, but only if they are related to the DayReport. I can't use account.reports, because that also contains other reports.

One approach I took is to create an instance method that uses a where clause to fetch the appropriate reports:

```
  def reports_for_account account
    reports.where(account: account)
  end
```

Problem is that this will trigger a query for each of the accounts, which I think is unnecessary. I'm only having trouble figuring out the correct approach.

Comment: `Problem is that this will trigger a query for each of the accounts` not sure what you mean here

Comment: Well, if I call this method for an account, it will trigger a query. So when displaying these day_reports for 10 accounts, I will end up with 1 query for the accounts, but then 1 query for every account to fetch the reports (so 10 in total)

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand it correctly.

You can decrease the numbers of quires by using [eager loadet association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) with: `.includes`, because includes will load (1. query) all records of the parent and (2. query) all of the records referenced in the includes method (where).

In `.where` you can look if the `day_report` id exists or is a certain id (i'm not quite sure for what you're asking here)

For example (with id):

`Account.includes(:reports).where(reports: {day_report_id: specified_id})`

Or if they have a relationship at all:

`Account.includes(:reports).where.not(reports: {day_report_id: nil})`

That would decrease the number of queries to two.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But for this, I still need to pass the day_report.id for each of those records. Since my starting point is displaying 25 day_reports, I need to do this query again 25 times, right?

Comment: No. Not if the day_record_id is the same for the 25 records. You could also set a limit, so you only receive 25 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `joins` helps you:

`Account.includes(:reports).joins(:day_reports)`

It fetches all accounts which have records in DayReport and preloaded `reports`.

Comment: There’s no direct relationship between account and day_report unfortunately, so I guess they join will not work.

Comment: It's not a problem - it made to INNER JOIN's. Look to is: Benefit.joins(:categories).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"benefits\".* FROM \"benefits\" INNER JOIN \"benefit_categories\" ON \"benefit_categories\".\"benefit_id\" = \"benefits\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"categories\" ON \"categories\".\"id\" = \"benefit_categories\".\"category_id\" WHERE \"benefits\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL"